# Reinstall Ubuntu and Keep SSH keys

Tags: ssh

I'm currently running Ubuntu 17.04 on my VPS. I want to go back to 16.04 since 17.04 is at end of life. I have a few remote systems that automatically log into this server using authorized keys. If I start fresh, how can I make sure those machines will still be able to log into the server. I do not have physical access to the remote machines.

Comment: I'd recommend simply backing up your `.ssh` folders and copying them into the new installation afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the user your other servers use to login, and copy that on your new VPS. That way your **SSH keys** will still be valid, and the other servers will be able to login.

However, with a new install you will also get a new **SSH fingerprint**, and the hosts will very likely refuse to log into your new VPS.

To remedy that you can either add `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to your SSH command (or via `~/.ssh/config`) on each and every host - which I don't recommend.

Or stop your servers from panicking about the new fingerprint, you can just re-create it:

The server credentials, that make up the "fingerprint" for SSH are actually just keypairs defined in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

Copy these files to your new VPS (with their .pub variants),  make sure the paths in `sshd_config` point to them and the permissions (`600` and `644`for the .pubs)  are correct, reload `sshd` on your new VPS, and you'll have essentially "cloned" your SSH setup.